# Как правильно настроить конфиг для виртуального хоста?

Tags: apache, docker, apache2

Есть запущенный докер контейнер, доступный по адресу [www.example.ru:8096](http://www.example.ru:8096). Как правильно настроить конфиг в Apache что бы доступ к этому контейнеру мог осуществляться по адресу service.example.ru

Comment: А это точно про docker/apache, Может DNS надо настроить?

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov Автор может забыл упомянуть. Обратное проксирование это хорошо, но толку если DNS о поддомене не знает

Comment: @ВадимАлександру В управление домена можно в настройках прописать что все поддомены принадлежат основному домену, и проблем с DNS не будет.

Comment: @IlyaDrummer wildcard запись для поддомена. Я знаю. Много кто меняет записи днс по старинке. Это вже же не отменяет факт того, что ответ автора может вести к заблуждению пользователей которые нашли этот ответ, ибо он не полный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел способ решения, создаем новый конфиг для виртуального хоста:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@site.com
    ServerName subdomin.site.com
    ServerAlias www.subdomin.site.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Location />
            ProxyPreserveHost On
            ProxyPass http://site.com:PORT/
            ProxyPassReverse http://site.com:PORT/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```